# Get the Age and Gender of iCloud User

Tags: swift, icloud, cloudkit

Is it possible to get the age and gender of a iCloud user that is logged in.  I know how to check if they are logged in, I know you can do this if the user is logged in with the facebook api.  But can you get the users age and gender if not logged in through facebook and just an icloud account.

I want to ensure above 18 age users do not share content with users below 18 when using cloudkit.

I am using swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get any other information than an ID from CloudKit. You can still get the name, but that function is depricated.

Comment: OK, thank you. Would your recommendation be just to ask the user for an age upon starting the app to get their age?

Comment: Or a warning with a button that says: 'I'm over 18'